# Enforce non-empty document in Monaco Editor

Tags: jsonschema, monaco-editor

Using the monaco editor playground (https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-json-defaults) it would seem that a completely empty document passes JSON schema validation.

I would think that the empty document should be interpretted as the null type and therefore require `{type: "null"}` in order to pass validation. Other libraries such as ajv (https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) interpret emptiness (`undefined`) as invalid for `{type: "object"}`

Is there a way to do this out of the box with monaco editor and json schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON syntax says that a JSON document starts with a value. An empty document is not the same as having "null" as content. Given that JSON schema defines constraints on the JSON input, an empty document, where nothing is here to apply the constraints, would be valid.